# Effort field GONE on a PBI, but still visibile in another one

Tags: tfs, scrum, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but I have a PBI where the effort is gone

[image]

and another PBI where I can see the effort.

[image]

This is affecting us because the first PBI is not counting towards the velocity.

anyone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule on the work item to hide empty readonly fields on the work item form. Since the PBI makes the Effort readonly when the state is done, it won't show up if it originally did not have a value.

I assume that you are working on a project in Visual Studio Online (visualstudio.com), and you cannot modify that behavior yet, but we are working hard to allow you to change the process: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online